# angular2 outsource code in service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have an angular2 app that displays chart data from a rest api.
I created the drawing code in my *bulletchart.component* file.
Now I want to outsource the code into a *service*.
But it seems like there is only one active instance of the data service.

This is my page content where I want to load the charts.

```
<div class="col">
   <app-bulletchart [ID]="1" [apiAddress]="'http://url1'"></app-bulletchart>
</div>
<div class="col">
   <app-bulletchart [ID]="2" [apiAddress]="'http://url2'"></app-bulletchart>
</div>
```

The template for the *app.bulletchart* is this:

```
<div class="panel test{{ID}}">
</div>
```

In my *bulletchart.service* file I change the DOM of the *app-bulletchart* with some methods like this:

```
initSvg() {
const identifier = '.test' + this.ID;

console.log("ident " + identifier);
this.svg = d3.select(identifier).append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'bullet')
```

There are also methods that update the chart

```
drawRange() {
console.log("range " + this.ID);

// Update the range rects.
const range = this.g.selectAll('rect.range')
  .data(this.ranges);

range.enter().append('rect')
```

I set the ID property of the *bulletchart.service* in the ngOnInit in *bulletchart.component*

But when I now try to use `this.bulletchart.drawRange();` this method is only called for ID 1 and **not** for ID 2.

I don't understand why, because I thought it would do something like this:

- create App-Bulletchart (ID=1) -> create instance of bulletchart.service (with ID = 1)
- create App-Bulletchart (ID=2) -> create instance of bulletchart.service (with ID = 2)

**Edit:**

I added `providers: [BulletchartService]` to my *bulletchart.component* file and removed it from the *app.module* and now it works.
But why?!

Comment: I wouldn't use services to modify a component. Services are injected so your components can use them to send and receive data and communicate to other components. The components themselves should be responsible for managing their own state.

Comment: @RobZuber But what should I use for outsourcing my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may include service provider in the component to ensure service is created for each instance of component

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers:[BulletchartService]
  ...
```

})

**Example**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
  Id: string;

  someMethod(){
    console.log(this.Id);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `<h1>Child ID {{Id}}</h1>
  <button (click)="invokeService()" >Invoke service</button>
  `,
  providers:[AppService]
})
export class ChildComponent { 
  @Input() Id: string; 

  constructor(private svc: AppService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.svc.Id = this.Id;
  }

  invokeService(){
    this.svc.someMethod();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <my-child [Id]="1" ></my-child>
  <my-child [Id]="2" ></my-child>
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular'; 
}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ChildComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YkwUtOYtaDglfC5MXiM5?p=info).

Hope this Helps!!